# Button is not responding to click event

Tags: android, events, event-handling

The button that i have used is not responding to the click event, i have added the onClickListener. i am new to android , plz tell me where am i going wrong.

```
public class Welcome extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    EditText range;    
    Button submit;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Log.i("MyActivity", "Entered ");

        try
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
            setContentView(R.layout.main2);
            Button submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnSubmit);
            EditText range= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditRange);
            TextView title=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            TextView notice=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtRange);
            EditText EditRange = null;    
            String value= EditRange.getText().toString();    
            final Bundle bundle= new Bundle();    
            bundle.putString("param1",value);    
            submit.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //Log.d("My Activity",e.getMessage());    
            e.printStackTrace();    
        } 
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        Log.i("MyActivity", "Entered OnClick()");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String value= range.getText().toString();
        final Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("param1",value);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Wait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), RoutePath.class);
        myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in setOnClickListener just put setOnClickListener(Welcome.this)

Comment: Skip the "Welcome ." part. Just pass "this" as parameter.

Comment: just put `setOnClickListener(this)`

Comment: just put welcome.this i think this should work.Also you will not get value in on click coz it is local to oncreate try to declare the string value above to onCreate.for EditText EditRange = null;

        String value= range.getText().toString();
try these

Answer (score 1):

For your activity use 
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

inside onClick() put whatever you want.